# Android_tutorials_image_transport Error inflating class org.ros.android.views.RosImageView

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run the image_transport tutorial under android_core on a Galaxy Nexus which is connected to my Ubuntu.

When I run it, I'm getting the following error from Logcat:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5149): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.ros.android.android_tutorial_image_transport/org.ros.android.android_tutorial_image_transport.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class org.ros.android.views.RosImageView

I deleted the line from main.xml that read android:src="@drawable/icon" and the same error still occured.

I have not modified the source code in MainActivity.java. Is there some revision that should be done?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36763/android_tutorials_image_transport--error-inflating-class-org.ros.android.views.rosimageview/) by [ruifei0713](https://answers.ros.org/users/2589/ruifei0713/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I think I had the same issue. Just change the org.ros.android.views...lines to org.ros.android.view...without s!

Best Regards

---

Originally posted by [ch1bo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2553/ch1bo/) with karma: 51 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-07-02**:
FYI, a fix for this has just been pushed.